# No delete statement sent by the JPA repository

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I have an integration test doing a delete on a child entity, but the delete statement is not seen in the log, and of course the test fails.

The log says:

```
2015-10-18 16:19:28,633 DEBUG  [TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor$CustomAnnotationTransactionAttributeSource] Adding transactional method 'deleteById' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
2015-10-18 16:19:28,633 DEBUG  [JpaTransactionManager] Creating new transaction with name [com.thalasoft.data.jpa.repository.GenericRepositoryImpl.deleteById]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
2015-10-18 16:19:28,634 DEBUG  [JpaTransactionManager] Opened new EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@5e020dd1] for JPA transaction
2015-10-18 16:19:28,635 DEBUG  [JpaTransactionManager] Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC transaction [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@f0c1ae1]
Hibernate:
    select
        userrole0_.id as id1_1_0_,
        userrole0_.version as version2_1_0_,
        userrole0_.role as role3_1_0_,
        userrole0_.user_id as user_id4_1_0_,
        user1_.id as id1_0_1_,
        user1_.version as version2_0_1_,
        user1_.confirmed_email as confirme3_0_1_,
        user1_.email as email4_0_1_,
        user1_.firstname as firstnam5_0_1_,
        user1_.lastname as lastname6_0_1_,
        user1_.password as password7_0_1_,
        user1_.password_salt as password8_0_1_,
        user1_.readable_password as readable9_0_1_,
        user1_.work_phone as work_ph10_0_1_
    from
        user_role userrole0_
    inner join
        user_account user1_
            on userrole0_.user_id=user1_.id
    where
        userrole0_.id=?
2015-10-18 16:19:28,636 DEBUG  [sqlonly]  com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:116)
3. select userrole0_.id as id1_1_0_, userrole0_.version as version2_1_0_, userrole0_.role as role3_1_0_,
userrole0_.user_id as user_id4_1_0_, user1_.id as id1_0_1_, user1_.version as version2_0_1_,
user1_.confirmed_email as confirme3_0_1_, user1_.email as email4_0_1_, user1_.firstname as
firstnam5_0_1_, user1_.lastname as lastname6_0_1_, user1_.password as password7_0_1_, user1_.password_salt
as password8_0_1_, user1_.readable_password as readable9_0_1_, user1_.work_phone as work_ph10_0_1_
from user_role userrole0_ inner join user_account user1_ on userrole0_.user_id=user1_.id where
userrole0_.id=3183
2015-10-18 16:19:28,636 DEBUG  [sqlonly]  com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:116)
3. select userrole0_.id as id1_1_0_, userrole0_.version as version2_1_0_, userrole0_.role as role3_1_0_,
userrole0_.user_id as user_id4_1_0_, user1_.id as id1_0_1_, user1_.version as version2_0_1_,
user1_.confirmed_email as confirme3_0_1_, user1_.email as email4_0_1_, user1_.firstname as
firstnam5_0_1_, user1_.lastname as lastname6_0_1_, user1_.password as password7_0_1_, user1_.password_salt
as password8_0_1_, user1_.readable_password as readable9_0_1_, user1_.work_phone as work_ph10_0_1_
from user_role userrole0_ inner join user_account user1_ on userrole0_.user_id=user1_.id where
userrole0_.id=3183
Hibernate:
    select
        userroles0_.user_id as user_id4_0_0_,
        userroles0_.id as id1_1_0_,
        userroles0_.id as id1_1_1_,
        userroles0_.version as version2_1_1_,
        userroles0_.role as role3_1_1_,
        userroles0_.user_id as user_id4_1_1_
    from
        user_role userroles0_
    where
        userroles0_.user_id=?
2015-10-18 16:19:28,654 DEBUG  [sqlonly]  com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:116)
3. select userroles0_.user_id as user_id4_0_0_, userroles0_.id as id1_1_0_, userroles0_.id as
id1_1_1_, userroles0_.version as version2_1_1_, userroles0_.role as role3_1_1_, userroles0_.user_id
as user_id4_1_1_ from user_role userroles0_ where userroles0_.user_id=6842
2015-10-18 16:19:28,654 DEBUG  [sqlonly]  com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:116)
3. select userroles0_.user_id as user_id4_0_0_, userroles0_.id as id1_1_0_, userroles0_.id as
id1_1_1_, userroles0_.version as version2_1_1_, userroles0_.role as role3_1_1_, userroles0_.user_id
as user_id4_1_1_ from user_role userroles0_ where userroles0_.user_id=6842
2015-10-18 16:19:28,664 DEBUG  [JpaTransactionManager] Initiating transaction commit
2015-10-18 16:19:28,665 DEBUG  [JpaTransactionManager] Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@5e020dd1]
2015-10-18 16:19:28,667 DEBUG  [JpaTransactionManager] Closing JPA EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@5e020dd1] after transaction
2015-10-18 16:19:28,667 DEBUG  [EntityManagerFactoryUtils] Closing JPA EntityManager
```

The test itself is not transactional:

```
@Test
public void testDeleteByUserRoleId() {
    UserRole loadedUserRole = userRoleRepository.findOne(userRole0.getId());
    assertNotNull(loadedUserRole);
    loadedUserRole = userRoleRepository.deleteById(userRole0.getId());
    UserRole myloadedUserRole = userRoleRepository.findOne(userRole0.getId());
    assertNull(myloadedUserRole);
}
```

The domain is:

```
@Entity
@SequenceGenerator(name = "id_generator", sequenceName = "sq_id_user_role")
public class UserRole extends BaseEntity {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    @JsonBackReference
    private User user;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String role;

    public UserRole() {
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return this.user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return this.role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "user_account")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "id_generator", sequenceName = "sq_id_user")
public class User extends BaseEntity {

  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String firstname;
  @Column(nullable = false)
  private String lastname;
  @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
  private EmailAddress email;
  @Column(nullable = false)
  private boolean confirmedEmail;
  @Column(length = 100)
  private String password;
  @Column(length = 50)
  private String passwordSalt;
  @Column(length = 50)
  private String readablePassword;
  private String workPhone;
  @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JsonManagedReference
  private Set<UserRole> userRoles = new HashSet<>();

  public User() {
  }

  public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
  }

  public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
    this.firstname = firstname;
  }

  public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
  }

  public void setLastname(String lastname) {
    this.lastname = lastname;
  }

  public EmailAddress getEmail() {
    return email;
  }

  public void setEmail(EmailAddress email) {
    this.email = email;
  }

  public boolean isConfirmedEmail() {
    return confirmedEmail;
  }

  public void setConfirmedEmail(boolean confirmedEmail) {
    this.confirmedEmail = confirmedEmail;
  }

  public String getPassword() {
    return password;
  }

  public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
  }

  public String getPasswordSalt() {
    return passwordSalt;
  }

  public void setPasswordSalt(String passwordSalt) {
    this.passwordSalt = passwordSalt;
  }

  public String getReadablePassword() {
    return readablePassword;
  }

  public void setReadablePassword(String readablePassword) {
    this.readablePassword = readablePassword;
  }

  public String getWorkPhone() {
    return workPhone;
  }

  public void setWorkPhone(String workPhone) {
    this.workPhone = workPhone;
  }

  public Set<UserRole> getUserRoles() {
    return userRoles;
  }

  public void setUserRoles(Set<UserRole> userRoles) {
    if (this.userRoles == null) {
      this.userRoles = userRoles;
    } else {
      this.userRoles.clear();
      this.userRoles.addAll(userRoles);
    }
  }

}
```

If I compare it to a very similar integration test, this one deleting a user entity instead of a user role, the log shows it's calling the delete statement:

```
2015-10-18 16:19:08,394 DEBUG  [TransactionalRepositoryProxyPostProcessor$CustomAnnotationTransactionAttributeSource] Adding transactional method 'deleteById' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
2015-10-18 16:19:08,395 DEBUG  [JpaTransactionManager] Creating new transaction with name [com.thalasoft.data.jpa.repository.GenericRepositoryImpl.deleteById]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; ''
2015-10-18 16:19:08,395 DEBUG  [JpaTransactionManager] Opened new EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@4086d8fb] for JPA transaction
2015-10-18 16:19:08,396 DEBUG  [JpaTransactionManager] Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC transaction [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@2e3572e8]
Hibernate:
    select
        user0_.id as id1_0_0_,
        user0_.version as version2_0_0_,
        user0_.confirmed_email as confirme3_0_0_,
        user0_.email as email4_0_0_,
        user0_.firstname as firstnam5_0_0_,
        user0_.lastname as lastname6_0_0_,
        user0_.password as password7_0_0_,
        user0_.password_salt as password8_0_0_,
        user0_.readable_password as readable9_0_0_,
        user0_.work_phone as work_ph10_0_0_,
        userroles1_.user_id as user_id4_0_1_,
        userroles1_.id as id1_1_1_,
        userroles1_.id as id1_1_2_,
        userroles1_.version as version2_1_2_,
        userroles1_.role as role3_1_2_,
        userroles1_.user_id as user_id4_1_2_
    from
        user_account user0_
    left outer join
        user_role userroles1_
            on user0_.id=userroles1_.user_id
    where
        user0_.id=?
2015-10-18 16:19:08,403 DEBUG  [sqlonly]  com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:116)
3. select user0_.id as id1_0_0_, user0_.version as version2_0_0_, user0_.confirmed_email as confirme3_0_0_,
user0_.email as email4_0_0_, user0_.firstname as firstnam5_0_0_, user0_.lastname as lastname6_0_0_,
user0_.password as password7_0_0_, user0_.password_salt as password8_0_0_, user0_.readable_password
as readable9_0_0_, user0_.work_phone as work_ph10_0_0_, userroles1_.user_id as user_id4_0_1_,
userroles1_.id as id1_1_1_, userroles1_.id as id1_1_2_, userroles1_.version as version2_1_2_,
userroles1_.role as role3_1_2_, userroles1_.user_id as user_id4_1_2_ from user_account user0_
left outer join user_role userroles1_ on user0_.id=userroles1_.user_id where user0_.id=6486
2015-10-18 16:19:08,403 DEBUG  [sqlonly]  com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:116)
3. select user0_.id as id1_0_0_, user0_.version as version2_0_0_, user0_.confirmed_email as confirme3_0_0_,
user0_.email as email4_0_0_, user0_.firstname as firstnam5_0_0_, user0_.lastname as lastname6_0_0_,
user0_.password as password7_0_0_, user0_.password_salt as password8_0_0_, user0_.readable_password
as readable9_0_0_, user0_.work_phone as work_ph10_0_0_, userroles1_.user_id as user_id4_0_1_,
userroles1_.id as id1_1_1_, userroles1_.id as id1_1_2_, userroles1_.version as version2_1_2_,
userroles1_.role as role3_1_2_, userroles1_.user_id as user_id4_1_2_ from user_account user0_
left outer join user_role userroles1_ on user0_.id=userroles1_.user_id where user0_.id=6486
2015-10-18 16:19:08,426 DEBUG  [JpaTransactionManager] Initiating transaction commit
2015-10-18 16:19:08,426 DEBUG  [JpaTransactionManager] Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@4086d8fb]
Hibernate:
    delete
    from
        user_account
    where
        id=?
        and version=?
2015-10-18 16:19:08,435 DEBUG  [sqlonly]  com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:147)
3. delete from user_account where id=6486 and version=0
2015-10-18 16:19:08,435 DEBUG  [sqlonly]  com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:147)
3. delete from user_account where id=6486 and version=0
2015-10-18 16:19:08,449 DEBUG  [JpaTransactionManager] Closing JPA EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@4086d8fb] after transaction
2015-10-18 16:19:08,449 DEBUG  [EntityManagerFactoryUtils] Closing JPA EntityManager
2015-10-18 16:19:08,450 DEBUG  [JpaTransactionManager] Creating new transaction with name [com.thalasoft.data.jpa.repository.GenericRepositoryImpl.findOne]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,readOnly; ''
2015-10-18 16:19:08,451 DEBUG  [JpaTransactionManager] Opened new EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@1f3b992] for JPA transaction
2015-10-18 16:19:08,451 DEBUG  [DataSourceUtils] Setting JDBC Connection [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection@6b63e6ad] read-only
2015-10-18 16:19:08,454 DEBUG  [JpaTransactionManager] Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC transaction [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@7beae796]
Hibernate:
    select
        user0_.id as id1_0_0_,
        user0_.version as version2_0_0_,
        user0_.confirmed_email as confirme3_0_0_,
        user0_.email as email4_0_0_,
        user0_.firstname as firstnam5_0_0_,
        user0_.lastname as lastname6_0_0_,
        user0_.password as password7_0_0_,
        user0_.password_salt as password8_0_0_,
        user0_.readable_password as readable9_0_0_,
        user0_.work_phone as work_ph10_0_0_,
        userroles1_.user_id as user_id4_0_1_,
        userroles1_.id as id1_1_1_,
        userroles1_.id as id1_1_2_,
        userroles1_.version as version2_1_2_,
        userroles1_.role as role3_1_2_,
        userroles1_.user_id as user_id4_1_2_
    from
        user_account user0_
    left outer join
        user_role userroles1_
            on user0_.id=userroles1_.user_id
    where
        user0_.id=?
2015-10-18 16:19:08,456 DEBUG  [sqlonly]  com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:116)
3. select user0_.id as id1_0_0_, user0_.version as version2_0_0_, user0_.confirmed_email as confirme3_0_0_,
user0_.email as email4_0_0_, user0_.firstname as firstnam5_0_0_, user0_.lastname as lastname6_0_0_,
user0_.password as password7_0_0_, user0_.password_salt as password8_0_0_, user0_.readable_password
as readable9_0_0_, user0_.work_phone as work_ph10_0_0_, userroles1_.user_id as user_id4_0_1_,
userroles1_.id as id1_1_1_, userroles1_.id as id1_1_2_, userroles1_.version as version2_1_2_,
userroles1_.role as role3_1_2_, userroles1_.user_id as user_id4_1_2_ from user_account user0_
left outer join user_role userroles1_ on user0_.id=userroles1_.user_id where user0_.id=6486

2015-10-18 16:19:08,456 DEBUG  [sqlonly]  com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:116)
3. select user0_.id as id1_0_0_, user0_.version as version2_0_0_, user0_.confirmed_email as confirme3_0_0_,
user0_.email as email4_0_0_, user0_.firstname as firstnam5_0_0_, user0_.lastname as lastname6_0_0_,
user0_.password as password7_0_0_, user0_.password_salt as password8_0_0_, user0_.readable_password
as readable9_0_0_, user0_.work_phone as work_ph10_0_0_, userroles1_.user_id as user_id4_0_1_,
userroles1_.id as id1_1_1_, userroles1_.id as id1_1_2_, userroles1_.version as version2_1_2_,
userroles1_.role as role3_1_2_, userroles1_.user_id as user_id4_1_2_ from user_account user0_
left outer join user_role userroles1_ on user0_.id=userroles1_.user_id where user0_.id=6486

2015-10-18 16:19:08,463 DEBUG  [JpaTransactionManager] Initiating transaction commit
2015-10-18 16:19:08,464 DEBUG  [JpaTransactionManager] Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@1f3b992]
2015-10-18 16:19:08,465 DEBUG  [DataSourceUtils] Resetting read-only flag of JDBC Connection [com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyConnection@6b63e6ad]
2015-10-18 16:19:08,466 DEBUG  [JpaTransactionManager] Closing JPA EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@1f3b992] after transaction
2015-10-18 16:19:08,466 DEBUG  [EntityManagerFactoryUtils] Closing JPA EntityManager
```

Note that the deleteById method is transactional, and is used by both user and user role delete integration tests:

```
@Override
@Transactional
public T deleteById(ID id) throws EntityNotFoundException {
    T entity = findOne(id);
    if (entity != null) {
        delete(entity);
    } else {
        throw new EntityNotFoundException("The entity could not be found and was not deleted");
    }
    return entity;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add `entityManager.flush()` after the delete statment

```
@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;

@Test
public void testDeleteByUserRoleId() {
    UserRole loadedUserRole = userRoleRepository.findOne(userRole0.getId());
    assertNotNull(loadedUserRole);
    loadedUserRole = userRoleRepository.deleteById(userRole0.getId());

    em.flush();    

    UserRole myloadedUserRole = userRoleRepository.findOne(userRole0.getId());
    assertNull(myloadedUserRole);
}
```

Comment: I added the deleteById method in my question to show it is transactional. I'm doing an integration test to test the repository and transaction manager as they would be used in production. I thus can't have a manual flush in the test as this would be a hack defeating the purpose of the test.

Comment: @Stephane Eybert: Before discussing whether it is good or not to have the flush method in the test, try it first, to check whether or not it make the test run!

Comment: I'm not arguing :-) So I put in a flush: userRoleRepository.getEntityManager().flush(); but got the following exception: javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: No EntityManager with actual transaction available for current thread - cannot reliably process 'flush' call. Is this because my test is not itself transactional ?

Comment: If your test class and test method does not have a `@Transactional` annotation, then I would expect this transaction. But this is very strange, because without a `@Transactional` around the complete method, the `deleteById(ID id)` method would have commit its transaction. (So the flush is not needed). Maybe the problem is a very different one.

Comment: I agree, it's something else... The test against the user entity works fine, only the one against the user role entity fails. I just published the whole project as a zip file at learnintouch.com/user-data.zip if you feel like having a look...

Answer (score 0):

This is not really a solution but more of an update on the issue.

After upgrading the project to `Spring Boot 2 2.0.3.RELEASE` and using an `assertEquals(Optional.empty(),myloadedUserRole);` the test passes successfully.

```
@Test
public void testDeleteById() {
    Optional<UserRole> loadedUserRole = userRoleRepository.findById(userRole0.getId());
    assertNotNull(loadedUserRole.get());
    UserRole deletedUserRole = userRoleRepository.deleteByUserRoleId(userRole0.getId());
    Optional<UserRole> myloadedUserRole = userRoleRepository.findById(userRole0.getId());
    assertEquals(Optional.empty(),myloadedUserRole);
}
```